# 'Error in' with no description Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Using angular cli and randomly started getting an error where it says "Error in" but then does not have any description.

Has anyone see this before or know how to fix it?

I am using Angular 5.0.0

```
"@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^5.0.1",
"@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.1.1",
"@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/material": "^5.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.0.0",


"@angular/cli": "1.5.0-beta.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.1",
```

Heres an open issue that is similar to mine but is not resolved.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7152

[image]

Comment: where does it say that? In the console or on the website?

Comment: it says it on the console @David normally it says error in then long error description with file names and stack trace all in red text. now it just says "Error in".

Comment: What has changed in your project since it was working before (as far as dependencies in your package.json)? (assuming it was working before and you've updated Angular)

Comment: @bazzells I generated a component but then went back and commented it all out and its still there. I moved a folder but I renamed all the imports and usually those show up as errors.

Comment: Can you paste the stack trace? It could be an install issue tho, I've had issues with updating Angular versions (5+) lately that have been resolved by removing node_modules, clearing npm cache, and re-installing.

Comment: @bazzells Thats the thing, there is no stack trace

Comment: its literally just "Error  in " blank

Comment: @bazzells I did remove node modules and re installed to no avail sadly.

Comment: Woah. Just saw your screenshot. Could be an issue with that beta version of the CLI.

Comment: Are you sure there are no black characters on your black background? Copy the whole stuff and paste it into a text editor.

Comment: I dont know why the beta version is broken but I was able to solve it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to resolve this issue by going to a non beta version as per bazzells comment

```
"@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
```

and then it said that

[image]

were unmet dependencies

```
"@angular/compiler": "^5.1.1",
"@angular/core": "^5.1.1",
```

so I updated those.

Thank you everyone for the help and hopefully this solves some peoples problems.